# from django.db import utils ImportError: cannot import name utils

Tags: django

As I am trying to import modules from ConceptNet (from conceptnet.models import Concept), I received this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/conceptnet/models.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.db import models
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in     <module>
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in    __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
return import_module('.base', backend_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in   import_module
__import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2  /base.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.db import utils
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

To be sure that this problem is not caused by something in ConceptNet, but rather by django.db, I tried, import django.db and that was sufficient to give me the same error. Something tells me that there is some circularity here: import django.db sets something in motion that at some point is trying to import something from django.db. I don't know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

See: [django-error #16136](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16136)

Check that you use a newer version of Django

Check your DATABASE CONFIG in settings.py:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  {
    'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

Check if your hosting provider has set up your db properly